# Evaluation of the determinant of a special $n\times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let us consider rational function  $A(x,n)$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}$, $x\in D=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{-1,1\}$):
$$A(x,n)=\det\begin{pmatrix}
1 &  [1]&0&0& \ldots & 0 &0\\
x^{1\times2}  &  [n-1] &[2]&0& \ldots & 0&0\\
x^{2\times3}  &  0 &[n-2]&[3]& \ldots & 0&0\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots&\vdots &\\
x^{(n-2)(n-1)}  & 0&0&  0       &\ldots & [2]&[n-1]\\
x^{(n-1)n}  & 0&0&  0       &\ldots & 0&[1]
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $[k] = \frac{1}{x^{2k}-1}$ and all coefficients belong to $\mathbb{R}$.

It seems to be eerie function, but I have a hypothesis (I checked it for $1\le n\le 8$) that for all $n$ and $x\in D$ we actually have $A(x,n)=(-1)^{n+1}$.

I tried to prove it but I failed.

Comment: Does this come from an exercize? Are you sure that a closed form could exist?

Comment: @Crostul This problem is not an exercize and I'm not sure that it has a good solution. But the fact that such a strange thing is always equal to 1 must have some explanations.

Comment: Anyway, for all $n$ you can easily see that $A(0,n) = (-1)^{n-1}$ (you get a triangular matrix, whose determinant is easy to compute).

Comment: @Crostul I corrected the text, there should be $|A(x,n)|.$

Comment: So my phone is cutting off the edges and I may be missing something critical, but...this matrix has lots of zeros. Did you already try cofactor expansion across the top row?

Comment: @PhillipHamilton Yes, I tried this approach, but it leads to a very terrible sum.

Comment: Can you show us, please, what the matrix looks like when $n=3$? Thank you.

Comment: @CatalinZara $$A(x,3)=\det\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{x^2-1} & 0\\ 
x^2 & \frac{1}{x^4-1} & \frac{1}{x^4-1}\\ 
x^6 & 0 & \frac{1}{x^2-1}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: @Andrey: Did you just edit the question and changed the determinant?

Comment: @CatalinZara Yes, I'm confused in the index, but now there all right.

Comment: Why did you rolled back my edit? The $[3]$ now is connected to $[2]$ by `\ddots`. That doesn't make sense, as the $[3]$ lies on the super diagonal but the $[2]$ lies on the main diagonal.

Comment: @Andrey: You may want to mention in the text of the question that you changed the matrix; people might still work on the original (incorrect) version ... As for the new version, correctly read (see comment by user1551), the determinant does appear to be as stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use Laplace's formula to reduce the calculation much simpler.

$\det A(x,n)=1\cdot \det A(x,n)_{1,1}-x^{1\cdot 2}\det A(x,n)_{2,1}+\cdots$.

Here $A(x,n)_{i,j}$ means the $(i,j)$-th minor of the matrix $A(x,n)$.

And each of the minors $A(x,n)_{i,1}$ is of 2-block-diagonal form and the two blocks are triangular.

So we can only extract and multiply the diagonal terms to compute the determinant of each minor.

Then the result is $\det A(x,n)_{i,1}=[1][2]\cdots [i-1]\cdot [n-i]\cdots [1]$.

What is left is just a simple high-school algebra.

---

FYI, I want to add the remaining details and its relation with q-binomials.

So, we have the formula

$ \det A(x,n)=\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1}x^{(i-1)i}[1]\cdots [i-1]\cdot [n-i]\cdots [1]$
$=[n-1]\cdots [1] \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1}x^{(i-1)i} \frac{[1]\cdots [i-1]}{[n-1]\cdots [n-i+1]}$.

The summands in the last expression are called [q-binomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient) $\binom{n-1}{i-1}_q$, for $q=x^2$ in this case.

So, ignoring the factor $[n-1]\cdots [1]$, what we want to show is the q-binomial theorem $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i q^{\frac{(i-1)i}{2}}\binom{n-1}{i}_q=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(1-q^i)$.

Comment: I believe that in the last formula the right part must be $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(1-q^i)$

Comment: @Andrey // Oh yeah you're totally right. Thank you for informing me.